# Using SinonJS to stub a library

Tags: node.js, tdd, sinon

I'm currently writing a NodeJS app and I'd like to write a test for a function.  SinonJS seems to be the spy/stub/mock library of choice, but I can't seem to figure out how to stub a method on a function.  For instance:

Lets say that I'm using a library called ExecSync.  I want to stub the `sh()` method on that library from within my Spec, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.  Would someone be kind enough to provide an example of stubbing a library method, from inside of a separate spec file?

To be clearer:

- spec.js - This is where I'm writing my test.
- util.js - This is where the method I'm testing exists.  The method calls execSync.sh() and is included via npm and `require()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some code would be good, but usually this can be achieved like this (using mocha)

```
describe('A test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    // what you want to stub is passed as a string
    sinon.stub(ExecSync, 'sh').yields(null,40);
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    ExecSync.restore();
  });

  it('has behaviour', function() {
    ExecSync.sh(function(err, res) {
      // err = null, res = 40
    });
  });
});
```

Another common practice when you cannot stub a dependency, is to write that dependency onto your module under test, such as

```
mymodule.ExecSync = function(arg) {
  ExecSync.sh(arg);
};
```

Then you can simply stub ExecSync on your module and never have to call the dependency at all.

Comment: Your second answer is clever.  Thanks for the help!